# Why is TFIDF seen as a model in gensim?

Tags: python, gensim

I am familiar with the tfidf vectorizer.

However, in gensim it seems like tfidf is treated as a model on itself, just like LDA, LSI and others.

Why is this the case? Can't tfidf not just be used to vectorize and then to input in an LDA model for example?

Link to documentation: https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/tut2.html

Comment: From the link you provided, it looks like they're vectorizing the corpus first then putting it into an LSI transformation which is standard. Looking at the [TFIDF Model](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/tfidfmodel.html) documentation, it looks to be the same as SkLearn's TFIDF, just in this case they use the word "model" to describe it.

Comment: @WStokvis so you think you can insert the tfidf vectorized document in an ldamodel for example?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what they do in the documentation

Comment: TDIDF is not a static transformation. The term frequencies need to be learned and stored (i.e. it is a model). You could learn the term frequencies with one corpus and transform another with it, so by making it a model in Gensim, it can be reused for multiple use cases.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful answer! @BrunoGL

Comment: @Daphne glad to be of help! I made it into an answer, so your question can be officially answered ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TFIDF is not a static transformation.

The term frequencies need to be learned and stored (i.e. it is a model).

This means that you could learn the term frequencies with one corpus and transform another with it, so by making it a model in Gensim, it can be reused for multiple use cases.

[Gensim TFIDF](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/tfidfmodel.html)

[Example on TFIDF](https://rare-technologies.com/pivoted-document-length-normalisation/)